# Host multiple DNN sites on one domain

Tags: installation, hosting, dotnetnuke, host

I am working with DNN from 5-6 months. Whenever I develop website, I have to show to client the demo link

http://www.webside.as/

but I have to wait for next demo to free this demo link.

Is there any possibility to host multiple DNN websites on one domain ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host multiple "sites" in DNN ("portals") from a single domain. Just go to the host/sites page and add a new "child" portal.

Comment: but when I want to upload the 1 portal on client's website. then how can I separately upload the one on the site ?

Comment: I would setup a new install for every one of your customers. It will be easier in the long run to deploy to the customers websites if you do it as separate installations.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up your DNS so that x.mysite.com all point to your DNN installation.

Then you ca easily create multiple sites as sub domains: a.mysite.com, etc.

By doing that you can avoid some issues that will occur when using parent/child sites.